# Dynamic Kafka Consumer with AOP

Tags: java, apache-kafka, aop, spring-aop, spring-kafka

I have got few dynamic Kafka consumers (based upon the department id, etc..) and you can find the code below.

Basically, I wanted to log the time taken for each `onMessage()` method call and so I have created a `@LogExecutionTime` method level custom annotation and added it for `onMessage()` method .
But my `logExecutionTime()` of `LogExecutionTimeAspect` never gets called even though my `onMessage()` is being invoked whenever there is a message on to the topic and everything else works fine.

Could you please help on what am I missing `LogExecutionTimeAspect` class so that it starts working?

**LogExecutionTime:**

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface LogExecutionTime {
}
```

**LogExecutionTimeAspect class:**

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class LogExecutionTimeAspect {
    @Around("within(com.myproject..*) && @annotation(LogExecutionTime)")
    public Object logExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        Object object = joinPoint.proceed();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(" Time taken by Listener ::"+(endTime-startTime)+"ms");
        return object;
    }
}
```

**DepartmentsMessageConsumer class:**

```
@Component
public class DepartmentsMessageConsumer implements MessageListener  {

    @Value(value = "${spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers}" )
    private String bootstrapAddress;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        Map<String, Object> consumerProperties = new HashMap<>();
        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, 
                                     bootstrapAddress);
        consumerProperties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "DEPT_ID_HERE");
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = 
            new ContainerProperties("com.myproj.depts.topic");
        containerProperties.setMessageListener(this);
        DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<String, Greeting> consumerFactory =
                new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerProperties, 
                    new StringDeserializer(), 
                    new JsonDeserializer<>(Department.class));
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer container =
                new ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<>(consumerFactory, 
                            containerProperties);
        container.start();
    }

    @Override
    @LogExecutionTime
    public void onMessage(Object message) {
        ConsumerRecord record = (ConsumerRecord) message;
        Department department = (Department)record.value();
        System.out.println(" department :: "+department);
    }
}
```

**ApplicationLauncher class:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableKafka
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.myproject" })
public class ApplicationLauncher extends SpringBootServletInitializer { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ApplicationLauncher.class, args);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy=true)`, but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider to turn on this option on the `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`:

```
/**
 * Indicate that the proxy should be exposed by the AOP framework as a {@code ThreadLocal}
 * for retrieval via the {@link org.springframework.aop.framework.AopContext} class.
 * Off by default, i.e. no guarantees that {@code AopContext} access will work.
 * @since 4.3.1
 */
boolean exposeProxy() default false;
```

On the other hand there is something like this, which is going to be better than AOP:

```
/**
 * A plugin interface that allows you to intercept (and possibly mutate) records received by the consumer. A primary use-case
 * is for third-party components to hook into the consumer applications for custom monitoring, logging, etc.
 *
 * <p>
 * This class will get consumer config properties via <code>configure()</code> method, including clientId assigned
 * by KafkaConsumer if not specified in the consumer config. The interceptor implementation needs to be aware that it will be
 * sharing consumer config namespace with other interceptors and serializers, and ensure that there are no conflicts.
 * <p>
 * Exceptions thrown by ConsumerInterceptor methods will be caught, logged, but not propagated further. As a result, if
 * the user configures the interceptor with the wrong key and value type parameters, the consumer will not throw an exception,
 * just log the errors.
 * <p>
 * ConsumerInterceptor callbacks are called from the same thread that invokes {@link org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer#poll(long)}.
 * <p>
 * Implement {@link org.apache.kafka.common.ClusterResourceListener} to receive cluster metadata once it's available. Please see the class documentation for ClusterResourceListener for more information.
 */
public interface ConsumerInterceptor<K, V> extends Configurable {
```

**UPDATE**

> `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy=true)` did not work and I know that I could use interceptor, but I wanted to make it working with AOP.

Then I suggest you to consider to separate a `DepartmentsMessageConsumer` and the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer`. I mean move that `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` into the separate `@Configuration` class. The `ApplicationLauncher` is a good candidate. Make it as a `@Bean` and dependent on your `DepartmentsMessageConsumer` for injection. The point is that you need to give an AOP a chance to instrument your `DepartmentsMessageConsumer`, but with the `@PostConstruct`, that's too early to instantiate and start consumption from Kafka.

Comment: `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(exposeProxy=true)` did not work and I know that I could use interceptor, but I wanted to make it working with AOP.

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in  my answer.

Comment: I have extracted the `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` creation into separate configuration and exposed as a Bean and now I get `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A org.springframework.kafka.listener.GenericMessageListener` implementation must be provided

Comment: I have updated my latest code to the question itself.

Comment: You still do there `containerProperties.setMessageListener(this);`, but that's wrong. You need to inject into that `concurrentMessageListenerContainer()` your `DepartmentsMessageConsumer`, however as an interface - `@Qualifier("departmentsMessageConsumer") MessageListener  messageListener`

Comment: Thanks a lot, got it, I was using `this`, which was wrong, need to use the same listener bean created by spring container, now, working now, great thanks again.